# How to fix "MISSING ESSENTIAL PLUGIN" in android studio ( Windows 10 )

Tags: android, android-studio

When I tried to open Android Studio, it showed an error.

I restarted and even reinstalled android studio but it is not working.

I also restarted my laptop.

```
 Corrupted Installation


Missing essential plugin:


    org.jetbrains.android


Please reinstall android studio from scratch.
```

[image of the error showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZZFp.png)

If you know how to fix it, then please say.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For `Windows` User
`C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.1\disabled_plugins.txt`

Hope this will fix Your Error

Answer (score 0):

Close Android Studio.
Find and delete this file:

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioYOURVERSION\disabled_plugins.txt
```